# Instantaneous axis of rotation and alpha

Tags: rotational-kinematics

Today my sir started rotation. He was teaching instantaneous axis of rotation. I understood it well. But later he was telling something about alpha. He was not clear . As far as I understand he said that we can't write
Omega=v/r.... (1)
as alpha =a/r... (2)
However, we can differentiate (1)  and get alpha.I don't remember it exactly. Does anyone seem to have any clue about he was taking. Just take a small illustration please

Comment: Unfortunately, since he wasn’t clear, this question isn’t clear either. Are you unable to ask your professor questions?

Comment: It's an online class , recording. I had it as backlog lol

Comment: Are we talking 2D or 3D?

Answer (score 0):

If you place a coordinate system on the center of rotation, then the velocity of each particle changes as a function of location only

$$ \vec{v}_i = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_i \tag{1}$$

where $\vec{\omega}$ is the rotational velocity *which is shared* with all the particles on the body at each time slice.

At a later time frame, if $\vec{\omega}$ is different we can define the rotational acceleration as

$$ \vec{\alpha} = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{\omega} \tag{2}$$

which allows us to define the acceleration of each particle as

$$ \vec{a}_i = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{v}_i $$

$$ \vec{a}_i = \left( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{\omega} \right) \times \vec{r}_i + \vec{\omega}_i \times \left( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{r}_i \right)$$ $$\vec{a}_i = \underbrace{ \vec{\alpha}\times \vec{r}_i }_{\text{Eulerian}}+ \underbrace{\vec{\omega}\times \left( \vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}_i \right)}_{\text{Centripetal}} \tag{3}$$

This is the summary of what you need to know about $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{\alpha}$.